# How can I push elements into an array that's within an object? (javascript/jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I push data stored within a list into a specific array ("items: [ ]") that's nested within an object?

```
  var obj = {
    name: customerName,
    items: [],
    price: [] }


     <ul>
        <li>Blah blah blah<li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: **obj.items.push()**

Comment: `obj.items.push('something')`

Answer (score 3):

```
obj.items.push(1);
obj.price.push(2);
```

Will result in:

```
{
    name: 'someName',
    items: [ 1 ],
    price: [ 2 ] 
}
```

To push data from your list items into the `items` Array you could do the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>

        <title>jQuery list</title>

        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>one</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>three</li>
        </ul>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var obj = {
                    items: []
                };

                $('li').each(function () {
                    // Extract the text node from the list item.
                    var textNode = $(this).text();

                    obj.items.push(textNode);
                });

                console.log(obj.items); // [ "one", "two", "three" ]
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! 

I have multiple <li> items in my list - and when I use this method to add them into my "items" array - it comes out as one long string instead of separate items in my array. 

How can I fix this?

Comment: @YNinNY do you mean you want to push the text node of your list items into the `items` Array?